# Protractor scripts failing when initiating API request using GOT

Tags: typescript, protractor, node.js-got

I am trying to migrate from [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

I can execute API calls using [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) successfully when executing a stand-alone javascript file using node

But I am facing challenge in executing the same [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) request from Protractor spec file.

**Folder structure**

```
.
├── build
│   ├── GotImpl.js
│   ├── basic-node-test.js
│   └── protractor-test.js
├── config
│   └── protractor.config.js
├── globals.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── GotImpl.ts
│   ├── basic-node-test.ts
│   └── protractor-test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

**./package.json**

```
{
  "name": "protractor-got",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GOT and Protractor Test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "got": "^11.5.2",
    "jasmine-data-provider": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-expect": "^4.0.3",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

**./tsconfig.js**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "outDir": "build", 
    "strict": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true 
  }
}
```

**./src/GotImpl.ts** - This class has a method ***executeGetRequest*** to execute a get operation based on the supplied requestURL

```js
const got = require('got');

export class GotImpl {
    options: any;
    responseBody: any;

    constructor() {
        this.options = {};
        this.options['headers'] = {};
        this.options['method'] = "GET";
        this.options.https = {};
        this.options.https.rejectUnauthorized = false;
    }

    async executeGetRequest(requestURL: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let successfulExecution: boolean = false;
            let apiRes = await got(requestURL, this.options);
            resolve(await apiRes.body);
        })

    }
}
```

**./src/basic-node-test.ts** - This file is a simple TypeScript file to execute a get operation by calling *executeGetRequest* method of *GotImpl* class

```js
import { GotImpl } from "./GotImpl"

(async () => {

    const gotTest = new GotImpl();
    await gotTest.executeGetRequest('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(async (responseBody) => {
        console.log('Response Body: ' + (await JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(responseBody), null, 5)));
    });
})();
```

**Output when executing basic-node-test.ts file [Successful Execution]**

```
$ node ./build/basic-node-test.js 
Response Body: {
     "userId": 1,
     "id": 1,
     "title": "delectus aut autem",
     "completed": false
}
```

## Problem

> Now, I am trying to execute ***executeGetRequest*** method (of ***GotImpl*** class) inside Protractor script

**./src/protractor-test.ts** - Protractor spec file

```js
import { GotImpl } from "./GotImpl";

describe('Got in Protractor', () => {
    it('Get Access Managers based on TIN', async (done) => {
        console.log("Start of GOT Test");
        const gotTest = new GotImpl();
        await gotTest.executeGetRequest('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(async (responseBody) => {
            console.log('Response Body: ' + (await JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(responseBody), null, 5)));
        });
        console.log("End of GOT Test")
        await done();
    });

    process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason) => {
        console.error(reason);
        process.exit(1);
    });

});
```

**./globals.js** - To capture global variables

```js
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = function setGlobals() {
  global.__root = path.dirname(fs.realpathSync(__filename));
  global.__specs = path.join(__root, "/build/");
};
```

**./config/protractor.config.js**

```js
require('../globals').call();

var chromeHeadless = {
    browserName: 'chrome',

    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--headless",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--window-size=800,600",
            '--disable-extensions',
            '--disable-plugins',
            '--disable-infobars'
        ],
        prefs: {
            'profile.password_manager_enabled': false,
            'credentials_enable_service': false,
            'password_manager_enabled': false
        }
    }
}

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: chromeHeadless,
    directConnect: true,
    specs: [__specs + 'protractor-test.js']
}
```

## Exception thrown in Protractor while executing the API request using got

```
$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./config/protractor.config.js 
Start of Protractor Test Execution
[21:00:19] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:00:19] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Inside On Prepare method
End.....
Start of GOT Test
RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/MONO-REPO/protractor-project/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:891:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/Users/xxxx/MONO-REPO/protractor-project/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  timings: {
    start: 1598493623188,
    socket: 1598493623189,
    lookup: 1598493623189,
    connect: undefined,
    secureConnect: undefined,
    upload: undefined,
    response: undefined,
    end: undefined,
    error: 1598493623190,
    abort: undefined,
    phases: {
      wait: 1,
      dns: 0,
      tcp: undefined,
      tls: undefined,
      request: undefined,
      firstByte: undefined,
      download: undefined,
      total: 2
    }
  }
}
[21:00:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

## Approaches taken so far

1. Disabled NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED
2. Set tunnel in options (in *GotImpl.ts*)

```
const tunnel = require('tunnel');
this.tunnelingAgent = tunnel.httpOverHttps({
            proxy: { // Proxy settings
                host: process.env.PROXY_HOST, // Defaults to 'localhost'
                port: process.env.PROXY_PORT, // Defaults to 80  
                proxyAuth: process.env.PROXY_AUTH,
            }
        });

this.options.agent = {};
this.options.agent.https = this.tunnelingAgent;
```

> Thanks for reading all through this point. Any help to resolve the **ECONNREFUSED** error is highly appreciated.

Comment: I use node 12.18.3

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same issue now

Comment: I moved out of protractor and used Jasmine framework directly for my script execution. As it is API, we don't really need protractor and the scripts can be executed as node scripts. I was able to execute the script successfully without Protractor. One additional GOT option to add is “http2”: true